# Why does scipy.signal.welch suppress zero frequency?

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing, spectral-density

I try to use whelch method and I found that zero frequency is abnormal

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100000
s = np.ones(n)
f, psd = signal.welch(s, return_onesided=False)
plt.plot(f, psd)
plt.show()
```

So result PSD is zero. 
Why does scipy.signal.welch suppress zero frequency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take another look at [the docstring for `welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html)  In particular, note the `detrend` argument.

The default `detrend` is `'constant'`, which subtracts the mean from the input before computing the spectrum.  To disable detrending, use `detrend=False`:

```
In [57]: from scipy.signal import welch

In [58]: from scipy.fftpack import fftshift

In [59]: n = 1000

In [60]: s = np.ones(n)

In [61]: f, psd = signal.welch(s, return_onesided=False, detrend=False)

In [62]: plot(fftshift(f), fftshift(psd))
Out[62]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10f8b6dd8>]
```

[image: plot]